# Simple CalDAV in Django

Tags: django, calendar, caldav

I'd like to have a simple read-only calendar on my Django website. The site would offer an URL which the users can put into their calendar apps so that their calendars sync with my website. The calendar should be read-only and accessible to anyone (anonymously). All the calendar event information I have in my other models, thus I don't need any CalDAV models to handle events, I would just generate the titles/descriptions/dates/etc from my existing models. I just need the required views for CalDAV to work properly, but I haven't been able to do it. How could I create such a simple calendar? What packages I need to install, and what should I add into my views.py and urls.py?

Comment: Just a note: I need CalDAV because my mobile phone doesn't support ICS/ICal syncing.

Comment: You have a phone which does support CalDAV but not iCal-over-HTTP? What kind of phone is that? :-)

Comment: Cyanogenmod doesn't support iCal-over-HTTP syncing. It would just download it and import to calendar, but not sync. At least, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://code.google.com/p/django-gcal/
It seems dated but it's a start.